# How can I award a bounty to two different answers?

Tags: support, bounties

So I have a bounty of 500 pending on a question that I wrote. Two different persons answered the question two different ways and I want to reward both.  I have discovered (to my dismay) that I can't split the bounty, so I thought I will award it twice, since I am allowed to place a second bounty on my question.  But there is this weird bounty-doubling rule and I am already at the max, and I did not see a tag or link to place another bounty on this.

It will be very painful to award this bounty to just one of the answers,  and I am willing to lose another 500 rep to award it to two answers, but I cannot see how to do that.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You have to wait until your current bounty ends before you can start another one. You can't have two bounties active on the same question at the same time.

So, you can award the bounty to one answer now, then start another bounty to award the other answer.

Comment: but i will not be forced to double that bounty, since it is already at the max, right?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Nope, a 500 point bounty is the max.