# How to choose the best answer for bounties

Tags: discussion, support, answers, bounties

I am in a problem. I made a bounty and I got 2 good answers, but they are "different". I know the bounty system is to award the effort and help others to find the best answer, and that is why I am worried for choosing the best answer.

The first answer (A) answers the question in 10 lines and links to a reference about it. It is clear, but there is no more info than what my specific case needs, so it only works for me.

The second answer (B) also answers the question in 100 lines, with no reference link. It answers my question, but it also answers other cases for other persons having different related problems than mine, and it gives too much information not really related to my issue.

Which should I choose?

How should I choose the best answer for bounties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't decide who to award the bounty to, they're all worthy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222305/282094), https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222305/282094,   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291320/282094, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264514/282094